# WooCommerce - how to tie quantity to size and color variations on product page

Tags: javascript, php, plugins, woocommerce

I'm working on a WP WooCommerce site, which retails t-shirts. I retrieve a quantity list from external API for each SKU on the product page, something like this:

SKU 1234

```
Size    Color    Quantity
S       Black    5
M       Black    3
M       Red      1
L       Black    7
L       Green    1
```

...................

I want to be able to tie each of the two properties of a SKU (color and size) to their respective dropdowns on the product page, meaning if the user selects SIZE M and then COLOR black I show a quantity of 3 (see data example above). How can I do that?